# Grpc channel not closing cleanly with ShutdownAsync

Tags: c#, grpc

I'd like to close my form app cleanly while a grpc call may be ongoing. I figured ShutdownAsync would close any ongoing calls but it seems like I'm either not putting it in the right place or it is not responsible for closing channels. What's the easiest way to do a catch-all, end all streams with `CompleteAsync()` when the application is closing?

There is the added difficulty that I'm using another class to hold all the grpc stuff and I'm not sure at what point things get garbage collected. Sure, I can do a cancellation token and have that cancel all ongoing calls when I close, but again, where should I do the cancelling? In the Model's destructor or the View's destructor?

Example code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Grpc.Core;
using OdinIntegrationSyncRPC;

namespace MinViaExample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ExampleModel ex;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ex = new ExampleModel();
        }

        private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ex.Sync();
        }

        private async void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            await ex.ShutdownChannelAsync();
        }
    }

    public class ExampleModel
    {
        Channel channel;
        OdinIntegrationSync.OdinIntegrationSyncClient client;

        private AsyncDuplexStreamingCall<LSHeartbeat, LastStudentsPacket> CurrentCall;

        public ExampleModel()
        {
            channel = new Channel("127.0.0.1:50052", ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
            client = new OdinIntegrationSync.OdinIntegrationSyncClient(channel);
        }

        public async void Sync()
        {
            var CTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
            CancellationToken CToken = CTokenSource.Token;

            using (CurrentCall = client.GetLastStudentSync())
            {
                await CurrentCall.RequestStream.WriteAsync(new LSHeartbeat() { ContinueRequest = true });

                while (await CurrentCall.ResponseStream.MoveNext(CancellationToken.None) && !CToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    LastStudentsPacket lsp = CurrentCall.ResponseStream.Current;
                    foreach (OStudent o in lsp.Students)
                    {
                        // blahblah
                    }
                    await CurrentCall.RequestStream.WriteAsync(new LSHeartbeat() { ContinueRequest = true });
                }
            }
            await CurrentCall.RequestStream.CompleteAsync();
        }

        public async Task ShutdownChannelAsync()
        {
            await channel.ShutdownAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: The above code has changed from initial question (added ShutdownChannel call to FormClosing). Now only the server crashes with a `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Already finished.'`. The client seems to exit cleanly.

Apologies if I'm missing something basic.

Comment: So what *are* you seeing? I wouldn't rely on a finalizer, to be honest - that makes things very non-deterministic. I would personally try to set up a cancellation token in the UI side and allow that to be cancelled when you want to exit.

Comment: @JonSkeet When would I cancel that token if, say, someone hits the X? In FormClosing?

Comment: Yes, that would seem reasonable.

Comment: @JonSkeet I ask because that didn't seem to work :) Should I just call `call.CompleteAsync`, or just `Channel.ShutdownAsync`, or both?

Comment: Well without any more detail than "didn't seem to work", it's hard to help you to be honest. We don't know whether the app didn't close, an exception was thrown, or something else entirely. (You report an exception at the bottom of your post, but not a complete stack trace or anything similar.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I edited the new code to reflect what I tried. Now the server crashes with an InvalidOperation `Already finished` exception.

Comment: Again, we don't know *where* it crashes (and we can't see any server code at all), or what the exception stack trace looks like. It's really, really hard to help you when you have so much relevant information that isn't included in the question.